# Redirect page to section on page load without JS

Tags: html, amp-html

In the website there is a top banner that needs to be hidden, and visible when the user scrolls up. In other words, the page needs to load to a specific section. The problem is that I can't use any JavaScript (including "on-load" function in the body tag), because the website is using [AMP](http://ampproject.org).

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [amp-position-observer](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-position-observer) with [amp-animation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-animation) in order to reach your aim

Comment: I followed the links and read the documentation on the AMPs site but couldn't figure it out... can you please provide some more information, really appreciate it.